# ASP.NET Capture and replace output in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

I need to replace some data that's sent from every page on my site, and I think doing it with Global.asax. This is what I have tried with so far:

```
void Application_PreSendRequestContent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Response.OutputStream);
    String output = sr.ReadToEnd();

    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Write("Testing..");
}
```

But this gives me an ArgumentException. What am I doing wrong? Is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Which line gives the ArgumentException? Is there a more detailed message in the exception?

Comment: The StreamReader-constructor throws ArgumentException saying that it could not read the stream. I've also tried doing it in the Application_BeginRequest-event as well reading from Response.Filter.

Comment: The correct way to do modification is through response filters. You can create a custom stream through which you can modify the actual response. You can check a working sample in this page https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/modifying-the-static-files-with-a-server-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there any better way to do this?

A [HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) might be the better choice for such a task.

For an example on how to modify the response of a request, have a look at this article: [Producing XHTML-Compliant Pages With Response Filters](http://web.archive.org/web/20140906104137/http://www.aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm going to look in to that.

Answer (score 1):

The post [Logging raw HTTP request/response in ASP.NET MVC & IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7) descibes very nicely exactly how to get a copy of the response.