# Read Request Body in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rest, httpwebrequest

How does one read the request body in ASP.NET?  I'm using the REST Client add-on for Firefox to form a GET request for a resource on a site I'm hosting locally, and in the Request Body I'm just putting the string "test" to try to read it on the server.

In the server code (which is a very simple MVC action) I have this:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
var inputString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But when I debug into it, `inputString` is always empty.  I'm not sure how else (such as in FireBug) to confirm that the request body is indeed being sent properly, I guess I'm just assuming that the add-on is doing that correctly.  Maybe I'm reading the value incorrectly?

Comment: Check out http://www.robertwray.co.uk/blog/2007/03/converting-requ.html

Comment: by request body, do you really mean the body - or everything including headers?

Comment: @Adam Tuliper: The body.  I don't have any custom headers for this request or anything special like that.  The end goal is to be able to pass a list of IDs to a RESTful resource.  Passing a single ID is easy as part of the route itself, but I'm not sure how to pass a list of IDs.  Though I'm certainly open to the possibility that I'm going about it the wrong way here.  (That is, expecting an XML string in the body.)

Comment: how would you do this in a GET request though? This would be in the querystring otherwise it would be a post request, no? I agree with Stripling below on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm misremembering my schooling, but I think GET requests don't actually *have* a body. [This page states](http://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/forms/methods.html#fund).

> The HTML specifications technically define the difference between "GET" and "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded (by a browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is to appear within a message body.

So maybe you're doing things correctly, but you have to POST data in order to have a message body?

#### Update

In response to your comment, the most "correct" RESTful way would be to send each of the values as its own parameter:

```
site.com/MyController/MyAction?id=1&id=2&id=3...
```

Then your action will auto-bind these if you give it an array parameter by the same name:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int[] id) {...}
```

Or if you're a masochist you can maybe try pulling the values out of `Request.QueryString` one at a time.

Comment: That's interesting.  It definitely makes sense.  But then the question would become, "What is the proper RESTful way to perform a request to _get_ a batch of specified items?"  That is, I need to pass a list of IDs to the resource in order to specify the list of items I want to retrieve.  One at a time is easy on the URL, but I don't want to have to hit the service thousands of times in one go.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess I was hoping that I could avoid query string parameters from a "clean URL" perspective.  The idea is that this service would be sort of a balance between API-usable and human-usable, and I wonder if we'd be putting an undue burden on consuming client developers to have a query string like that.

Comment: Additionally, it just occurred to me that this would easily hit the request length boundary when we're talking about upwards of 1,000 IDs.  I think I need to re-think this...

Comment: @David: Yeah. Even though there isn't an official maximum request length (http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html), if the URL is more than a thousand characters, you're probably not following good practices. You might look at using something like OData's URI conventions (http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/uri-conventions) so you can request batches based on criteria and skip/take parameters instead of requesting items explicitly by ID.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently reminded of this old question, and wanted to add another answer for completeness based on more recent implementations in my own work.

For reference, [I've blogged on the subject](http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2014/02/its-ok-to-use-post.html) recently.

Essentially, the heart of this question was, "How can I pass larger and more complex search criteria to a resource to GET a filtered list of objects?"  And it ended up boiling down to two choices:

1. A bunch of GET query string parameters
2. A POST with a DTO in the request body

The first option isn't ideal, because implementation is ugly and the URL will likely exceed a maximum length at some point.  The second option, while functional, just didn't sit right with me in a "RESTful" sense.  After all, I'm *GETting* data, right?

However, keep in mind that I'm not *just* GETting data.  I'm *creating* a list of objects.  Each object already exists, but the *list* itself doesn't.  It's a brand new thing, created by issuing search/filter criteria to the complete repository of objects on the server.  (After all, remember that a collection of objects is still, itself, an object.)

It's a purely semantic difference, but a decidedly important one.  Because, at its simplest, it means I can comfortably use POST to issue these search criteria to the server.  The response is data which I receive, so I'm "getting" data.  But I'm not "GETting" data in the sense that I'm actually performing an act of creation, creating a new instance of a list of objects which happens to be composed of pre-existing elements.

I'll fully admit that the limitation was never technical, it was just semantic.  It just never "sat right" with me.  A non-technical problem demands a non-technical solution, in this case a semantic one.  Looking at the problem from a slightly different semantic viewpoint resulted in a much cleaner solution, which happened to be the solution I ended up using in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the GET/POST issue, I did discover that you need to set the Request.InputStream position back to the start. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792864/258081) I found.

Specifically the comment

> Request.InputStream // make sure to reset the Position after reading or later reads may fail

Which I translated into

```
Request.InputStream.Seek(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the HttpClient (available via Nuget) for doing this type of thing.  Its so much easier than the System.Net objects

Answer (score 0):

Direct reading from the Request.InputStream dangerous because when re-reading will get null even if the data exists. This is verified in practice.
Reliable reading is performed as follows:

```
/*Returns a string representing the content of the body 
of the HTTP-request.*/
public static string GetFromBodyString(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    if (request == null || request.InputStream == null)
        return result;

    request.InputStream.Position = 0;

    /*create a new thread in the memory to save the original 
    source form as may be required to read many of the 
    body of the current HTTP- request*/
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        request.InputStream.CopyToMemoryStream(memoryStream);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/*Copies bytes from the given stream MemoryStream and writes 
them to another stream.*/
public static void CopyToMemoryStream(this Stream source, MemoryStream destination)
{
    if (source.CanSeek)
    {
        int pos = (int)destination.Position;
        int length = (int)(source.Length - source.Position) + pos;
        destination.SetLength(length);

        while (pos < length)
            pos += source.Read(destination.GetBuffer(), pos, length - pos);
    }
    else
        source.CopyTo((Stream)destination);
}
```

Comment: `request.InputStream` is always Not null, what you could test is `request.InputStream.CanRead && request.InputStream.CanSeek` so you can safely re-position the cursor in the stream and later can read it...