# how do I log requests and responses for debugging in servicestack

Tags: logging, servicestack

I would like to log the entire request & response pair for a servicestack webservice.
I've looked at the response filer, however the stream exposed is read only.

Answer (score 12):

Have you seen ServiceStack's built-in [Request Logger](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) Plugin?
It's a configurable In Memory, CSV or Redis Request Logger that maintains a log / (error responses) of the recent requests.

If you would like a different behaviour, you can implement and register your own [IRequestLogger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequestLogger.cs), it gets called for every request. It's log method gets called for every request with the following parameters.

```
Log(IRequest httpReq, object requestDto, object response, TimeSpan duration);
```

From the `IRequest` you can get the original .NET Core/ASP.NET/HttpListener Request / Response types with

```
var originalReq = httpReq.OriginalRequest;
var originalRes = httpReq.OriginalResponse;
```

#### Filtering the response

Otherwise the ways to introspect the Response is with either

- The [Response Filter](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters) or [Response Filter Attributes](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes); or
- Overriding [OnAfterExecute()](https://docs.servicestack.net/customize-http-responses#intercept-service-requests) on your own base class that inherits from Rest/ServiceBase

Comment: I added `Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature(){ RequiredRoles = new string[]{}});` to the AppHostBase.Configure() but when I visit the `/api/requestlogs` it's blank, a breakpoint shows the `Run` method in my ServiceBase<RegisterNewMember> is being executed.

Comment: It works for me, everywhere I use it. You can see it enabled and working in the SocialBootstrapApi demo template: https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi

Comment: bootstrap is blank too, but I noticed the json version has data, but the duration is not numeric... Error: Parse error on line 1:
`...},"requestDuration":PT0.8884481S},{"id":`
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

Comment: Also ... Which method would be best if I want to inspect/log the raw xml from both request & response? P.S. sorry: I didn't intend to use up so much of your time :-}

Comment: Use the Network tab in Chrome WebInspector or Fiddler for HTTP traffic. Whilst WireShark shows you everything.

Comment: ok, This is server-server communication so I'll have to grapple with wireshark :-)

Comment: oh, would something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084459/logging-raw-and-compressed-http-responses-in-asp-net-iis7 work if I wanted to log the raw data?

Comment: @mythz where can I register the `IRequestLogger`? There's no doco on how to register it, I assume it just automatically finds it?

Comment: @mythz we want to log requests to a txt file, no route or anything like that. So we don't need the RequestLogsFeature. Just want to capture/log.

Comment: NEVER mind. I registered it wrong, its being picked up fine. :) Sorry.

Comment: Has anyone created one a RequestLogger to write to Azure table storage? Pretty simple to modify the sample stuff in ServiceStack but no point reinventing the wheel....

Comment: @mythz, is there a way to do this for a particular request and not all requests?

Comment: @JaredBeach You can specify which requests to skip with the `SkipLogging` predicate returning true on all requests but the ones you want logged. Whilst the `ExcludeRequestDtoTypes` collection lets you specify Request DTOs you want excluded.

Comment: @mythz figured out how to do it with an attribute https://gist.github.com/jmbeach/7f0a8a9371e72e8f5f73e3b6470fb6a4

Comment: @JaredBeach that's just doing simple text logging, it's not using the much more detailed [request logger](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger).

Comment: Request attribute version works perfectly for my use case. Just a temporary solution to see if a third party is integrating with our app correctly. May be worth adding this approach to your answer.

Comment: @JaredBeach You're welcome to include your own answer here.

Answer (score 1):

This RequestFilter allows you to print raw request content. You could modify it to get more information like headers and cookies if desired. As @mythz notes in a comment, this is less detailed than the Request Logger plugin. But if you only want to add logging for a single request, it could be preferable. *Disclaimer*: this code is probably not production-ready and I'm not using it for production.

```cs
public class RequestDataSpyAttribute : RequestFilterAttribute
{
    // gets injected by ServiceStack
    public ILog Log { get; set; }

    private readonly string _logMessage;

    public RequestDataSpyAttribute(string logMessage)
    {
        _logMessage = logMessage;
    }

    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object requestDto)
    {
        System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper original = req.OriginalRequest as System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper;
        if (original == null)
            return;

        Log.Debug($"{_logMessage} Request: {original.InputStream.ReadToEnd()}");
    }
}
```