# How do I log ServiceStack requests and responses to a database?

Tags: logging, servicestack

I want to log all ServiceStack requests, to include:

- Request DTO
- Response
- Date
- Time
- Url
- IP
- Execution Time

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I log requests and responses for debugging in servicestack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605935/how-do-i-log-requests-and-responses-for-debugging-in-servicestack)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at ServiceStack's [Request Logger Plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) which already does a lot of this.

Comment: i was defined `CustomLogger` implement `IRequestLogger`,

in `Log(IRequest request,object requestDto,object response,TimeSpan elapsed)` method,i can logging some requestlog.

but,is ServiecStack's HttpResonse StatusCode is not `200`, the `Log` method is not work.
how to log `ValidatorError` or `httperror`?