# ASP.NET save respose to file in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, save, global-asax, outputstream

I have a problematic bug in a production system, which I simply can’t find. Sometimes the system produces an invalid link. When the end-user clicks it I get an error report from the system, and the end-user gets an error message. The URL’s that fail are like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/somepath/undefined/
```

The “undefined” part is the problem, which I think is produced by JavaScript, but I like to make sure it’s not from the back-end.

Is there a way to save every response to a file if it contains the string “/undefined/” using global.asax?

I’ve tried this:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        TextReader t = new StreamReader(Response.OutputStream);
        string content = t.ReadToEnd();
        // look for "/undefined/" and save to a temp file is the easy part after this
    }
```

But is says that OutputStream is not readable.

I don’t know for certain which page/ajax request that produces the faulty link, so I need to inspect every response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot read the response stream, but you can add a response filter to the output stream, and get a copy of it.

There are several related artiles on this:

- [Logging raw HTTP request/response in ASP.NET MVC & IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792864/102112) here at
  SO
- [Capturing and Transforming ASP.NET Output with
  Response.Filter](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/13/Capturing-and-Transforming-ASPNET-Output-with-ResponseFilter) by Rick Strahl.

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Juest check the IIS log file. I tracks all request with urls

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But i don't see how that will help. The IIS log only tells me which URL's that have been requested. Not what produced the faulty URL.