# Get raw HTTP request as it comes to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, http

I want to get HTTP request as string, not as parsed `HttpRequestBase` object, but like:

```
GET /gb/images/v1_3fc5b988.png HTTP/1.1
Host: ssl.gstatic.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox&referrer=utm_source%3Dmozilla%26utm_medium%3Dsnippet%26utm_campaign%3Drugoogleplay
Connection: keep-alive
```

in a regular asp.net mvc3 method. Is it possible or I should write out own HTTP handler?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logging raw HTTP request/response in ASP.NET MVC & IIS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7)

Comment: Oh - good call.  Didn't see this when I was responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen is the **SaveAs** method, which saves to disk - not a great option.  I did look at that code and it does pretty much what you'd expect.  Perhaps an extension method on **HttpRequestBase**, based on code from **SaveAs**, would do?

To save some hassle, here's the framework's implementation of **SaveAs**:

```
    public void SaveAs(string filename, bool includeHeaders)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(filename) && RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(this._context).HttpRuntime.RequireRootedSaveAsPath)
        {
            object[] objArray = new object[] { filename };
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("SaveAs_requires_rooted_path", objArray));
        }
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        try
        {
            if (includeHeaders)
            {
                TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
                streamWriter.Write(string.Concat(this.HttpMethod, " ", this.Path));
                string queryStringText = this.QueryStringText;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryStringText))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(string.Concat("?", queryStringText));
                }
                if (this._wr == null)
                {
                    streamWriter.Write("\r\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(string.Concat(" ", this._wr.GetHttpVersion(), "\r\n"));
                    streamWriter.Write(this.CombineAllHeaders(true));
                }
                streamWriter.Write("\r\n");
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            ((HttpInputStream)this.InputStream).WriteTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```