# Logging restful calls

Tags: c#, rest

No. 1
I'm currently working on a C# .Net component that makes calls to external restful web services. I would like to implement a mechanism for logging/capturing both outgoing calls (requests) and incoming calls (responses) then save them in our local database. This is not about consuming a a restful service rather about logging what goes on the wire both ways, can someone please advise me of best approach of achieving this.

No.2
Can someone help me understand the main difference when it comes to logging Restful calls vs Soap calls. I do understand the difference in architecture and implementation. I only want to understand the main difference when it comes to logging incoming and outgoing calls.

Any help with No. 1 will really be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do post you two questions separately!

Comment: take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most commonly used tool for logging is log4net.
So on every outgoing call just make an LogInfo record and this way on the fly you can monitor what goes in and out