# catch all incoming request to asp.net mvc controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

Is there any way to catch all incoming requests to controllers without using `ActionFilter`'s before handling requests by asp.net?

Comment: Something like an ISAPI filter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524610(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I doubt you need an isapi filter, rather you'd want something at asp.net level. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rodneyviana/archive/2014/02/06/logging-incoming-requests-and-responses-in-an-asp-net-or-wcf-application-in-compatibility-mode.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7

Comment: @WiktorZychla thanks for your reply, Thats what I want, IHttpModule.

Answer (score -1):

in your `Startup.cs` file place this code into the `Configure()` method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseMvc();

    //your code below
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        string body;
        using (Stream receiveStream = context.Request.Body)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                body = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(body.ToString());
    });


}
```

then pls note the `app.UseMvc()` always has a priority, meaning any route specified in your app goes to the controller only. so either specify another route, or dont work with routes in your MVC but instead place your routing into the interception within `app.Run(async (context)`