# Trying to read api response in global.asax

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse, httpcontext

trying to read HttpContext.Current.Response in Application_EndRequest at global.asax. I tried using filters, but the CanRead and CanSeek objects are always set to false.

Comment: Try looking at this link below, it might help.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792864/4583393

Comment: thats what I tried, but the CanRead and CanSeek are always set to false, so itll always return an empty string(the filter)