# Write the contents of Response.OutputStream also to a text file before replying back to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));
```

In order to directly write some lines of text and send them to the browser as an attachment.

I now though also want to save that text locally in a file, but Id rather avoid changing too much of my code. Can I write the contents of `Response.OutputStream` into a text file before ending the response?

Comment: How / what are you writing to the stream? You have not included any code that actually does the work.

Comment: @mortb that should not be relevatn. It's simply a streamWriter so I have a few `writer.Write()` commands that write some strings into it.

Comment: The code that exectues is *always* relevant. Most of us on SO is problem finders searching for patterns in the code.There is always more than one solution and the context the code is running in might contain the clues we need to help you.

Comment: Response.Filter might be the solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter(v=vs.110).aspx
If I'm correct you could create a filter (which is an implementation of a stream) that both saves the page and passes on the data unaltered.

Comment: I was not aware of this existing at all. So practically what you are suggesting is having a filter that will inherit my `StreamWriter` and use that  to also save the stream in a file before ending my Response?

Comment: Basically yes, but inherit from `Stream`not `StreamWriter`. I must say though, that I have not yet tried this solution myself :)

Comment: Seems like a good solution, I will certainly give it a try and report back if I manage it.

Comment: Such a `Stream` is also implemented as part of the [`IHttpModule` solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792864/1178314) I have linked in my answer. You could reuse that part for trying the filter solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you ask for is not doable. I am quite sure `Response.OutpuStream` is not seekable (property `CanSeek` yielding `false`), meaning you won't be able to get at its start for reading its content. It is probably not readable either (property `CanRead` yielding `false`).

Attempting any of those operations would yield a `NotSupportedException`.

If your needs are for some basic logging, you may work around that by [enabling .Net standard network traces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Or code an `IHttpModule` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792864/1178314).

Otherwise, you may use an intermediate `MemoryStream` with your `StreamWriter`, then reset this `MemoryStream` to `Position` 0, write it to `OutputStream`, reset it again to `Position` 0, write it to your file.

Comment: In the end using a MemoryStream seemed like a good and fast solution so I ended up following your advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CopyTo method of the Stream object. At the end you can copy the whole OutputStream to an other one which write it to a file. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `Response.OuputStream` is not seekable as far as I know, your suggestion should lead to a `NotSupportedException`.

Comment: Frédéric is right. As MSDN states the CopyTo method can throw NotSupported exception is the current stream does not support reading.