# Serialize HttpListenerContext C#

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize `HttpListenerContext` instance. But there are some mutable properties in this class, that cause side effects and `JsonConverter` just throw an error, when try to serialize an instance of this class.

What is the best solution for this problem? I see next ways to deal with it:

1. Create custom wrapper class and list all necessary fields in it
2. Write custom `ContractResolver` with tricky condition for serializable properties (for example: serialize only auto properties)

Can you suggest something? What is a general approach for this situation? How should I serialize mutable objects from external libraries?

For serialization, I use `Newtonsoft.Json` library and serialize object with `JsonConverter.SerializeObject(...)` method.

Comment: I think this is very dependent on which library you are using. So please tell us which library you are using for serialization. Most libraries come with Attributes to handle this.

Comment: @Sebi I use `Newtonsoft.Json` lib. But I can't mark `HttpListenerContext` class with some attributes, because this class from external lib.

Comment: True story, then you will need a wrapper class.

Comment: Why do you need to serialize this object? For logging?

Comment: @Ygalbel Yes, I want to log incoming requests to server.

Comment: You don't need to serialize it as JSON you can log http raw data, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7)

Comment: 1) Do you only need to serialize `HttpListenerContext` or do you need to deserialize also?  2) You wrote, *`JsonConverter` just throw an error, when try to serialize an instance of this class.*  What is the error?  Can you share what you attempted so far as a [mcve]?