# Read HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, global-asax

How I can read the whole content of `HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream` in Global.asax End_Request?

I want to get the text of content that is sent to browser? I tried to google it, but didn't found something useful.

Actually I hope this is possible and I will not need to create a filter or something for this simple requirement.

Thank you.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819326/asp-net-capture-and-replace-output-in-global-asax

Comment: Sad...it looks like there is not an "easy" way and I must to create a  filter for that :( Thank you anyway!