# How to access response body in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, .net-4.8

I can add headers via:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Key", "Value");
```

and then access the value in the header through:

```
var header = Response.Headers["Key"];
```

I was wondering if there was any way to access the body of a response in a similar way. i.e. when I write `Response.Write("Hello World");` I want to be able to get that 'Hello World'. there's a `Response.Output._charBuffer` which kinda does the job but then again it's accessible Privately.

Update:
I just want to check if the response body is empty or not. I don't actually need the body itself.

Comment: You need to send a POST which is an HTTP with a body.  Read with InputStream of the response : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.inputstream?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for your answer, but inputStream gets the response from request. I want to be able to get the body of the response I'm sending, not the request I'm receiving.

Comment: In this [Request and response operations in ASP.NET Coret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/request-response?view=aspnetcore-5.0) you can see sample that is what do you want to do. for .Net 5

Comment: @Faraz thanks for the resource, but I'm using .net 4.5 not core.

Comment: There is no differences in the structure of a request or a response.  The  request and response both have headers and a body, and both can both be read as a stream or as text.

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to store and read only strings from the Response object? If so you can do something like this

```
  using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Response.Body))
  {
      var stringResult = sr.ReadToEnd(); //This should be equal to "Hello World"
  }
```

**Update**: I red your comment that you are working on .NET 4.5. Try this then:

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Response.OutputStream))
 {
      var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but `HttpContext.Response.Body` works in .net core, I'm using .net framework 4.x which doesn't include a Body in `HttpContext.Response`.

Comment: I've added a suggestion for .NET 4.5

Comment: Using StreamReader returns the error `Stream was not readable`.

Comment: Sorry I had to test this first, apparently the isn't an easy way to achieve this .NET 4.5 Please review this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819326/asp-net-capture-and-replace-output-in-global-asax